# X11 - put image in XY format

Tags: x11, xorg, xcb

XCB library provides function `xcb_put_image`. The signature of the function is:

`xcb_void_cookie_t xcb_put_image(
    xcb_connection_t *conn,
    uint8_t format,
    xcb_drawable_t drawable,
    xcb_gcontext_t gc,
    uint16_t width, uint16_t height,
    int16_t dst_x, int16_t dst_y,
    uint8_t left_pad,
    uint8_t depth,
    uint32_t data_len, const uint8_t *data
)`

The function fills given `drawable` (window/pixmap) with pixels colors from `data`. `format` argument specifies how given data should be interpreted by the X server.

One of three possible values of `format` is XCB_IMAGE_FORMAT_XY_PIXMAP which means that bytes contained in `data` should be interpreted as XY pixmap (three consecutive "greyscale" images - one for each RGB channel).

Here is my problem: suppose I want to fill the pixmap with yellow 10x10 rectangle and I want to use XY pixmap format. In order to do this, I need to fill `data` with `data_len` bytes. What should be the number and the values of the bytes in the array?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the visual that is used for a drawable. You do not really want to know all the details about visuals, but https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/visual-types.html is a good start.

If you are free to assume a "sane" X11 server with little endian byte order, your visual will most likely be of type TrueColor with one byte for red, green and blue. Yellow can then be produced by mixing full red and green with no blue.

I don't remember the definition of XYPixmap, but if you are right, then this would need 200 bytes with value 255 followed by 100 bytes with value 0.
(left_pad would be zero in this case).